# Exclude a package from build path in POM

Tags: java, maven, buildpath

I have a package `de.ht.ak.praktikum.hook` in a project which is in a source folder `src` but it should be excluded from build path. I used to do this with right click on it and choosing Build Path -> Exclude. Since I added maven to the project every time I update the project the excluded folder turns into package again, i.e. the exclusion gets deleted. I tried to fix it this way:

```xml
...
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>de/ht/ak/praktikum/hook</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    ...
    </build>
...
```

I tried also to do it as described [there](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/specifying-source-path-inclusions-and-exclusions.html):

```xml
...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <sourceExcludes>
                <sourceExclude>de/ht/ak/praktikum/hook/</sourceExclude>
            </sourceExcludes>
            <sourceIncludes>
                <sourceInclude>**/*.java</sourceInclude>
            </sourceIncludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
```

However none of the both methods help. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want to export the package in the jar then just add internal in package name e.g.: de.ht.ak.praktikum.internal.hook

Comment: I don't use maven to build the project but just to manage dependencies. Exclusion of the mentioned folder should serve to hide the project errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt won't work because you're specifying to exclude it as a *resource* (i.e., those files that get packaged in your resulting JAR file - you don't usually want source files to be among them).

The second attempt is more on the right track. However, you want to exclude them from compilation, hence you need to set [the `exclude` option of the `maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html). I.e., like this:

```
<build>
  ..
  <plugins>
    ..
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>de/ht/ak/praktikum/hook/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ..
  </plugins>
</build>
```

When updating the project in Eclipse (Maven -> Update Project), Eclipse should honor this configuration and also exclude it from the Eclipse-internal build path.

Comment: My POM looks like [this](http://pastie.org/9686444) now, but it doesn't help - the folder is still included in the build path.

Comment: Why did you leave out the `*.java` wildcard pattern specifier? Also, some people report success with the source folder prepended to the exclude pattern, some people without. To be on the safe side, try putting `**/` at the beginning of the pattern (i.e., `**/de/ht/ak/praktikum/hook/*.java`.

Comment: I'd like to exclude the whole folder. It doesn't matter though. If I use the wildcard pattern specifier or not. The result is the same.

Comment: I finally figured out what was the problem. If I wanted to exclude the files I would have to use `<exclude>de/ht/ak/praktikum/hook/**/*.java</exclude>` because there are several further packages in `hook`. But my goal was to exclude the whole folder and I could achieve this with `<exclude>de/ht/ak/praktikum/hook/*</exclude>`.